# Limit of function using L'Hôpital's rule: $\lim_{x \to \infty}{x-x^2\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})}$

Tags: limits

I have to calculate $\lim_{x \to \infty}{x-x^2\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})}$. I rewrote it as $\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{x-x^3\ln^2(1+\frac{1}{x})}{1 + x\ln(1+\frac{1} {x})}}$ and tried to apply L'Hôpital's rule but it didn't work. How to end this?

Comment: You could try substituting $\frac{1}{x}=t$

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1702282/using-lhospital-solve-lim-x-to-infty-x-x2-ln1-frac1x

Answer (score 3):

Make the substitution $t=\dfrac{1}{x}$. Then, $x\to\infty \implies t\to 0$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x-x^2\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\\ = \lim_{t\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{t^2}\ln(1+t)\right)\\= \lim_{t\to 0}\left(\frac{t-\ln(1+t)}{t^2}\right)$$

This comes out as $\frac{0}{0}$ on direct plugging of values, so it's ready for some L'Hopital bash.

$$\lim_{t\to 0}\left(\dfrac{1-\frac{1}{1+t}}{2t}\right)$$

Again, by direct plugging, we get $\frac{0}{0}$, so recursion of L'Hopital will work.

$$\lim_{t\to 0}\left(\dfrac{0+\frac{1}{(1+t)^2}}{2}\right)=\lim_{t\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{2(1+t)^2}\right)=\boxed{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Comment: Ideally, you should simplify your limit $ \displaystyle \lim_{t \to 0} \left ( \frac {1 - \frac 1{1+t}} {2t} \right ) $ first.

Comment: @GohP.iHan, well, I was thinking that doing so will make it messier, so I continued from that. Simpler way for the win! :D

Answer (score 0):

The reason why L'Hôpital's rule didn't work is that you added on a determined-term into the limit, i.e.
$$
1 + x \ln \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right) 
=
1 + \ln \left( \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)^x \right)
\to 
1 + \ln \left( e \right)= 2
$$
when $x \to \infty$. Another approach with the one from Prasun Biswas is using the Taylor series for $1/x$, for $x>1$:
\begin{align}
x - x^2 \ln \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)
&=
x - 
x^2
\left( \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{ k} \frac{1}{x^k} \right)
=
x - 
x^2
\left( 
\frac{1}{x}
-
\frac{1}{2x^2}
+
\sum_{k=3}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} \frac{1}{x^k}
 \right)
\\
&=
\frac{1}{2}
+
\sum_{k=3}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} \frac{1}{x^{k-2}}
\end{align}
Letting $x \to \infty$, one ends up the limit with $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: yes, right. I was my typos and I edited the post.