# using L'Hospital solve $\lim_{x \to \infty} x - x^{2}\ln(1 + \frac{1}{x})$

Tags: derivatives

I can't get this to $ = \frac{0}{0}$ form so I can use l'Hospital rule
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} x - x^{2}\ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)$$

tips?

[EDIT]
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x} - \frac{\ln(1 + x)}{x^{2}}$$
second term $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1 + x)}{x^{2}} = 
\lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{\frac{1}{1 + x}}{2x} =
2\lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{x}{x+1} = 0$$
first term
$$ \lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{1}{x} = \infty$$

is this okey?

Comment: Hint: for $x\to\infty$, $\ln(1+\frac1x)=\frac1x-\frac{1}{2x^2}+o(\frac{1}{x^2})$.

Comment: Let $x=1/t$. We are interested in $\frac{t-\ln(1+t)}{t^2}$ as $t$ approaches $0$ from the right.

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Letting $y=1/x$ gives

> $$\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{y-\ln(1+y)} {y^2}. $$

I think you can see it now!

Comment: I edited my post, is it okay now?

Comment: You should work with the form in my answer!

Comment: ok got it thanks

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1207250/limit-of-function-using-lh%C3%B4pitals-rule

Answer (score 0):

$t=1/x$  so $x=1/t$

$$\lim_{t\to 0} 1/t-(1/t)^2\ln(1+t) $$

$$=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{t-\ln(1+t)}{t^2}$$

L'Hopital:

$$=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1-1/(t+1)} {2t} $$

$$=\frac 1 2\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{t} {\frac{(t+1)(t(t+1))}{t+1}}$$

assume $\frac{t}{t+1}\neq 0$

$$=\frac 1 2\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{1+t}=\color{red}{\frac 1 2}$$